# Get movies that have categories

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have associative table movies and their categories.

```
movie_id catagory_id
   1         1
   1         2
   1         3
   2         1
   2         2
   2         4
   3         1
   3         5
   3         6
```

How can i get movies that have category 1 and 2?

Result:

```
movie_id
   1
   2
```

Comment: @NicoHaase It only comes to mind to make a selection for films with category 1, and a selection for films with category 2, and then look at their intersection. But if I need many categories? These are too many requests

Comment: 1) Do a GROUP BY. 2) Use HAVING, with COUNT(DISTINCT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` with `COUNT DISTINCT` to make sure both 1 and 2 are there.

```
select movie_id
from table
where category_id in (1, 2)
group by movie_id
having count(distinct category_id) = 2
```

Just for fun, you can also do a *self join*:

```
select m1.movie_id
from table m1
join table m2 on m1.movie_id = m2.movie_id
where m1.category_id = 1
  and m2.category_id = 2
```

Or, use `INTERSECT`:

```
select movie_id from table where category_id = 1
INTERSECT
select movie_id from table where category_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why we need distinct there? For case when movie can have same category twice?

Comment: Exactly, use distinct to make sure a movie having same category twice isn't returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want have `catagory_id` 1 and 2 use this:

```sql
select movie_id from your_table
group by movie_id
having string_agg(catagory_id::text, ',' order by catagory_id) ~ '(1,)+(2)+'
```

If you want have `catagory_id` 1 or 2 use this:

```sql
select distinct(movie_id) from your_table
where catagory_id in (1, 2)
```

Comment: `catagory_id = 1 and catagory_id = 2` is always `false`

Comment: yep, doesnt work

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct movie_id from ...` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate all the categories of each movie in an array and then filter those that contain all the target categories in `having` clause. The `contains` array operator is handy for the job.

```sql
 select movie_id from t
 group by movie_id
 having array_agg(catagory_id) @> array[1,2];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this.

```
select movie_id 
from movies m 
join categories c on c.movie_id = m.movie_id and c.category_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: Please add some explanaiton to your answer such that others can learn from it. Are you sure this will only list those movies that are assigned to **both** categories?